# Reading Web service, I have a WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am normally used to using JSON/REST. I have been given access to a web service with WSDL file that I need to use to read data. I have no idea where to start

What is the quickest easiest way to get JAVA code up and running that can query this web "service"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use libraries like [Apache AXIS](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), which include a WSDL2Java program you can run to parse the WSDL definition file and generate classes that let you invoke the web service.

Comment: I will read about both of them. Seems odd that there would be two separate apache projects that do the same thing (:

Comment: The Apache Foundation does not decide as a group which projects should be worked on - other groups donate code and projects to them. For example there are at least 3 Apache projects that build your (Java) code

Answer (score 1):

1. Pick your framework (popular ones include Axis2, Spring-WS, Jax-WS). 2. Use the tool that comes with your framework to create Java proxies (for example, for Axis2, you'll use wsdl2java). 3. Write code that uses the generated proxies to actually call your web service.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Sun's JAX-WS (now built-in to Java 6).  Google it (I can only post one link, below).

Some links...

Main site:
jax-ws.dev.java.net/

JAX-WS is under the Glassfish Metro project, but you don't need Glassfish to use it (we don't).  However this is a good resource:

metro.dev.java.net/guide/

For starting with WSDL, see specifically:

https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/Developing_client_application_with_locally_packaged_WSDL.html